# Is it wrong to include circular dependencies in two structs in two different header files?

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor, header-files

I have a very large program which is not compiling and I suspect it has to do with circular dependencies across structs. When I code it like the below, it will not compile

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO

#include "bar.h"


typedef struct _foo Foo;

struct _foo{
  Bar *bar;
}

#endif
```

**bar.h**

```
#ifndef BAR
#define BAR

#include "foo.h"

typedef struct _bar Bar;

struct _bar{
  Foo *foo;
}

#endif
```

But if I completely muck up my design and create a **common.h** file, and put all the struct declarations in there, it seems to work.

**common.h**

```
#ifndef COMMON
#define COMMON

typedef struct _foo Foo;
typedef struct _bar Bar;

#endif
```

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO

#include "common.h"
#include "bar.h"

struct _foo{
  Bar *bar;
}

#endif
```

**bar.h**

```
#ifndef BAR
#define BAR

#include "common.h"
#include "foo.h"

struct _bar{
  Foo *foo;
}

#endif
```

This seems like really bad design. Furthermore, I though that the header guards were meant to prevent issues arising out of circular includes. Am I supposed to use the **common.h** approach, or am I doing something else wrong that it is making my first solution fail?

Comment: Circular inclusion is always wrong.

Comment: "header guards were meant to prevent issues arising out of circular includes". Include guards are meant *to break the cycle*. Which makes circualr inclusion pointless (since guards will stop it anyway). However, include guards do not help you to solve dependency issues you were trying to solve by using circular inclusion in the first place.

Comment: @AnT then for simplicity, would it make sense to just *dump* all struct declarations in a single header file? My concern is that I am going to end up with a common.h file with structs declared which have nothing to do with one another

Comment: Sometimes having an `appdata.h` (or `common.h`) is a good idea because it provides a way to *refactor* your code to avoid the circular reference problem to begin with.

Comment: @puk: The proper strategy is to *stratify* your headers into levels. Higer-level headers include lower-level headers (but not the other way around). If lower-level header has declaration dependency on higher-level header, an appropriate forward declaration is added to the lower-level header. This means that lower-level headers should be designed to get by with opaque pointers to higher-level data.

Comment: @AnT could you please provide an example

Comment: Your example is good enough. Just assume that `foo.h` a lower-level header and `bar.h` a higher-level header. Include `foo.h` into `bar.h` (just like you do now), but don't include `bar.h` into `foo.h`. Instead simply add `typedef struct _bar Bar;` to `foo.h`. Done. (And don't forget semicolons at the end of struct type declarations).

Comment: @AnT Circular inclusion is fine, and is the most sensible way to think about certain tasks. Suppose you have two components that need to know about each other, and you can't guarantee that one component will exist before the other. The solution is to simply acknowledge this constraint and work around it.

Comment: @David: Maybe, but I don't see the point. Include guards will prevent circular inclusion anyway - they will turn it into sequential inclusion. In that case why not just use sequential inclusion from the get go?

Comment: @AnT If I have two big components A and B and each is 200 lines long I don't really want to have to combine them into a single 400 line file.

Comment: @David: "Combine"??? I never said that you have to combine. My advice is to keep them as separate headers, but decide which one is higher-level and which-one is lower-level. The higher-level one will `#include`, the lower-level one will rely on forward declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every type has to be *declared* (but not necessarily *defined*) before you use it. This doesn't happen in your first approach. Suppose you were to include `bar.h` in your main program. Because `foo.h` is included there, and due to the structure of your header guards, the compiler generates something like:

```
typedef struct _foo Foo;

struct _foo{
  Bar *bar;
}

typedef struct _bar Bar;

struct _bar{
  Foo *foo;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
  //Program stuff
}
```

Which it then tries to compile from top to bottom. The problem is that it hits the definition

```
struct _foo{
  Bar *bar;
}
```

and doesn't know what to do because the compiler hasn't seen `Bar` yet.

The solution is to use a *forward declaration* to declare to the compiler that that there will be a type called `struct _bar` and you promise that you'll define this type later. For example, the following compiles just fine:

```
struct _bar; //Forward declaration of 'struct _bar'

struct _foo{ //Definition of 'struct _foo'
  struct _bar myBar;
}

struct _bar{ //Definition of 'struct _bar'
  struct _foo myFoo;
}
```

In your case in particular it would be good form to either put all forward declarations in a dedicated header file, or to just forward declare each type in each header file. For example:

**bar.h**

```
#ifndef BAR
#define BAR

struct _foo; //Defined in foo.h, circular dependency

struct _bar{
  struct _foo *foo;
}

#endif
```

**foo.h**

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO

struct _bar; //Defined in bar.h, circular dependency

struct _foo{
  struct _bar *bar;
}

#endif
```

As has been pointed out in the comments, the header guards do not "solve" this problem for you- they merely prevent each header file from being included more than once (which typically causes redefinition errors). The correct solution is to make sure that the compiler knows about every type you're going to use before you use it.

Comment: You don't need separate forward declarations for `struct` tags except for function arguments.

Comment: Two quesitons. 1) Is it not bad to have random forward declarations floating around? For example, if I define in one header file then forward declare in 100 other files it just seems bad to me. and 2) can I forward declare with a `typedef` for simplicity (I am noticing some dissatisfaction at my use of `typedef`)

Comment: @puk For a large project I would tend to create a single header file that includes all definitions. For a small project, or one where your structs are so tightly coupled where they can't be used anywhere else, having two mutual forward declarations isn't a problem.

Comment: @David you would **define** all structs in a single file or would you **declare** all the structs in a single file?

Comment: @puk Define. You'd have to use a forward declaration here or there to resolve any circular dependencies, but generally separate declarations are unnecessary.

Comment: `struct _bar; 

struct _foo{ 
  struct _bar myBar;
}

struct _bar{
  struct _foo myFoo;
}` does _not_ "compiles just fine".  Review need for `;` and `*`  Other code samples have compiler problems too.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with mutually recursive structures in different files.

The main problem here is that the circular inclusions don't work. It's easy to solve this, however, because neither header must include the other at all.

If you skip the `typedef`, you can do this:

```
// In a.h
struct a {
    struct b *ptr;
};
```

and

```
// In b.h
struct b {
    struct a *ptr;
};
```

### Alternatively

If you want to use the typedef, you'll just have to skip using it inside the structure definitions.

```
// In a.h
struct a {
    // Have to use 'struct b' instead of 'b' because we can't guarantee
    // that the typedef for b is visible yet.
    struct b *ptr;
};
typedef struct a a;
```

and

```
// In b.h
struct b {
    // Have to use 'struct a' instead of 'a' because we can't guarantee
    // that the typedef for a is visible yet.
    struct a *ptr;
};
typedef struct b b;
```

Comment: So if I use `struct a *ptr;` instead of `typedef struct a A;...;A *ptr` then I can have circular dependencies? This contrasts with AnT's comment above

Comment: @puk: AnT was talking about circular header file inclusions.

Comment: @puk: Also note that there's no particular reason why you would want to name it `struct _bar` instead of just `struct bar`. Since `struct bar` is fine, why not do that?

Comment: I saw the convention with the underscore for struct names somewhere and started using it.

Comment: My problem is that these structs **are** in different header files, hence the circular header file inclusions.

Comment: @puk: Right, stop doing that. So `a.h` does not include `b.h`, and `b.h` does not include `a.h`.  See the code I've posted, notice that there are no `#include` statements anywhere.

Comment: I will try to combine into a single file, but it is not always that clear cut

Comment: @puk: Again, **you do not have to combine them into a single file.**

Comment: Why is it that the compiler can get by without a forward declaration when `struct b *ptr` is used (first example) but cannot do so if `typef` used and then `B *ptr` (not in examples).

Comment: When you write `struct b *ptr;` you get the forward declaration for free. That's not true for typedefs—the compiler has no way of knowing what kind of pointer it is.

Answer (score 1):

With the following C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
    Foo f = { NULL };
    Bar b = { NULL };
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The preprocessor outputs the following (not including the contents of stdio.h):

```
# 2 "x1.c" 2
# 1 "foo.h" 1



# 1 "bar.h" 1



# 1 "foo.h" 1
# 5 "bar.h" 2

typedef struct _bar Bar;

struct _bar{
  Foo *foo;
}
# 5 "foo.h" 2
typedef struct _foo Foo;

struct _foo{
  Bar *bar;
}
# 3 "x1.c" 2


int main()
{
    Foo f = { ((void *)0) };
    Bar b = { ((void *)0) };
    printf("hello\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the typedef for `Foo` comes **after** it is referenced.  This is what causes the errors.  Because `Foo` and `Bar` depend on each other, it is good practice to define both in the same header with the typedefs for each first.

Comment: EPIC answer detected. Thank you, that is very **very** helpful

Answer (score 0):

I see an obvious problem-- On the header guard for `foo.h`, you're using the name of the struct as the guard. That should instead be all-caps for a macro. I would guess this is some sort of IDE auto-replace that slipped into your code by accident?

The problems you're having may extend beyond, this, but still. =]

Comment: Sorry, I quickly whipped this up. I will edit right now